# Whether $\varphi(E)$ is a Jordan measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Definition: A set $S \subset \mathbb {R^{n}}$  is **Jordan measurable**   if it is bounded in $\mathbb {R^{n}}$ and  its boundary is  a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

The following conclusion has been proved to be correct.

> Let $\varphi : \Omega\subset \mathbb {R^{n}} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ be a $C^{1}$ function in the open set $\Omega$. Let $E$ be a compact Jordan measurable set with $ E\subset  \Omega$ .
>   If $\varphi $ is a diffeomorphism on the interior of $E$, then $\varphi(E)$ is a compact Jordan measurable set.

I want to relax one condition from the above conclusion,
replacing the condition

"Let $E$ be a compact Jordan measurable set with $ E\subset  \Omega$ "

with

"Let $E$ be a Jordan measurable set with $ \overline{E}\subset  \Omega$".

> Do we have that $\varphi(E)$  is a Jordan measurable set?

By my intuition, $\varphi(E)$  may not be  a Jordan measurable set.
Then I try to find some examples to support my view,
let $\varphi(x)=\tan(x)$, $E= \Omega=(0,\pi/2)$. $\overline{E}\not\subset \Omega $, although $\varphi(E)$ is not a Jordan measurable set and  $\varphi $ is a diffeomorphism on the interior of $E$.

Unfortunately,since $\overline{E}\not\subset \Omega $, my example fails to satisfy the changed condition.I want to find a 
example strictly denying "$\varphi(E)$  is a Jordan measurable set". I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I edited your question trying to make it clearer. I hope I didn't change the original meaning. Feel free to modify it again if you think you can improve it.

Comment: @Del:Thanks for your edit.I improve it again to  express  my original meaning better.